# Let $0<\varepsilon <1$. Construct a set $E \subset [0,1]$ such that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and for which $0<m(E)\le \varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Let $0<\varepsilon <1$. Construct a set $E \subset [0,1]$ such that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and for which $0<m(E)\le \varepsilon$.

Let $E = [0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$. Now since this is countable set it satisfies the condition $m(E) \le \varepsilon$. I'm having trouble showing that this set is dense in $[0,1]$.

If $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$, then for every open $O \subset [0,1]$ we would need that $E \cap O \ne \emptyset$. So let $O$ be open in $[0,1]$. Then there exists $(a,b) \subset O$ If now $$E \cap O= \emptyset$$ then $$E \cap (a,b) = ([0,1] \cap \Bbb Q) \cap (a,b) = \emptyset$$ I'm trying to get to the argument that this would imply that $\Bbb Q \cap (a,b)$ is empty which is a contradiction since there is always a rational between two real numbers. How can I show this?

Also where does the strict inequality come from for $m(E) > 0$? The Lebesgue measure can be zero right?

Comment: $E=[0,\varepsilon]\cup (\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]).$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prove it by contradiction: indeed you already know that there exists a rational $c$ between $a$ in $b$, so $c\in E\cap (a,b)$, and $E\cap (a,b)$ is not empty.

On the other hand, it is true that $m(E)=0$, so it does not meet your requirements. An easy solution in to consider $E\cup (0,\varepsilon)$, whose measure is $\varepsilon$ and which is dense in $[0,1]$, as it contains $E$ that is dense in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of $E$ does not work  because $m(E)=0$. Arrange the rationals in $[0,1]$ in a sequence $\{r_n\}$ and consider the intervals $(r_n-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{n+1}}, r_n+\frac {\epsilon} {2^{n+1}})$. The union of these intervals is dense (becasue it contains all rational numbers in $[0,1]$) and its measure is at most $\sum \frac  {\epsilon} {2^{n}}=\epsilon$.